# No output when crawling a webpage using scrapy

Tags: python, scrapy

I am trying to get the name of all building that are shown in that page. Since I want more data that is inside of each related link. I tried to use Scrapy crawl. At first Jeg tried to get just the name of the building.

My code :

```
    import scrapy
    from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
    from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
    #from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess
    
    
    class AkershusSpider(CrawlSpider):
        name = 'akershus'
        allowed_domains = ['akershuseiendom.no']
        start_urls = ['http://akershuseiendom.no/lokaler',]
    
        rules = (
            Rule(LinkExtractor(restrict_xpaths='//*[@class="items animate-3"]/a'), callback='parse_item', follow=True),
        )
    
        def parse_item(self, response):
           yield {
             'Bygget': response.xpath('//*[@id="html"]/body/div[1]/main/article/header/div[2]/h1').get()  
           }
           
    #process=CrawlerProcess()
    #process.crawl(AkershusSpider)
    #process.start()
```

When I run this script I don't get any output....

the terminal shows among other things :

```
*022-11-23 23:49:53 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect] DEBUG: Redirecting (301) to <GET https://akershuseiendom.no/lokaler> from <GET http://akershuseiendom.no/lokaler>
2022-11-23 23:49:54 [filelock] DEBUG: Attempting to acquire lock 2380446210848 on C:\Users\103720nutr\Documents\scripts\eiendomsverdi\venv\lib\site-packages\tldextract\.suffix_cache/publicsuffix.org-tlds\de84b5ca2167d4c83e38fb162f2e8738.tldextract.json.lock
2022-11-23 23:49:54 [filelock] DEBUG: Lock 2380446210848 acquired on C:\Users\103720nutr\Documents\scripts\eiendomsverdi\venv\lib\site-packages\tldextract\.suffix_cache/publicsuffix.org-tlds\de84b5ca2167d4c83e38fb162f2e8738.tldextract.json.lock
2022-11-23 23:49:54 [filelock] DEBUG: Attempting to release lock 2380446210848 on C:\Users\103720nutr\Documents\scripts\eiendomsverdi\venv\lib\site-packages\tldextract\.suffix_cache/publicsuffix.org-tlds\de84b5ca2167d4c83e38fb162f2e8738.tldextract.json.lock
2022-11-23 23:49:54 [filelock] DEBUG: Lock 2380446210848 released on C:\Users\103720nutr\Documents\scripts\eiendomsverdi\venv\lib\site-packages\tldextract\.suffix_cache/publicsuffix.org-tlds\de84b5ca2167d4c83e38fb162f2e8738.tldextract.json.lock
2022-11-23 23:49:54 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://akershuseiendom.no/lokaler> (referer: None)
2022-11-23 23:49:54 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
2022-11-23 23:49:54 [scrapy.statscollectors] INFO: Dumping Scrapy stats:
{'downloader/request_bytes': 450,
 'downloader/request_count': 2,*
```

I've trying to find out what is going on but without hell.

Comment: that means that there is something wrong with your selectors

Comment: no.. i found out that this website has extremely dynamic. text shows up just by scrolling. do you know how to do it in scrapy crawl ?

Comment: Yes... if a page is dynamic then that means you are likely using selectors that don't exist... which is still a problem with your selectors.  Unless there is an obvious api the website uses, you will probably need to use scrapy-splash or scrapy-playwright